# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' PYTHON 3 BS4

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

```
# LIBRAIRIES

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


# SEARCH URL

url = 'https://www.atlas-monde.net/tous-les-pays/'
response = requests.get(url)

# EXTRACT DATAS

if response.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    # items = soup.find_all(class_="sidebar")
    items = soup.find_all("td")
    for i in items:
        print(i.string + '\n')


# CREATE DATAS FIELD

with open('persons.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    for item in items:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        filewriter.writerow(item)
```

Hello
I can't convert the scrapped data into a CSV file.
I have the following error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're opening it as a binary file, but you should open it as a text file. Change this:

```
with open('persons.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
```

To this:

```
with open('persons.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

Comment: use `newline=''` as well for Python 3.  See [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).